# Rollup image webpage display template

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, display-template

I have a web page and I've set a rollup image in its properties. What I would like to do is to display this image when this web page appears in a search result. I've tried to modify Item_WebPage.html and add PublishingRollupImage to ManagedPropertyMapping at the top of that html file but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've finally solved that problem. I didn't understand that I needed to create a new display Template instead of editing the default one.